# How to make turtles move around patches with specific rules?

Tags: netlogo

I am new to Netlogo, and have some questions. That would be great if you could help me.

I would like to create some fruit flies moving around a tree that is made up by green patches. Fruit flies are attracted to the tree. They will turn back to the tree if fruit flies move away certain distance (such as 5 grids) from the tree.

In the beginning, they will not stop on the green patches because they have enough energy. As time passed, they will loss their energy. They will find the closest green patch, and stay on it for certain time once their energy reaches 0. They gain energy after that, and they only can do short hops from the bottom branch to the top one (3 hops). Flies will move back to the bottom branch when they are on the top part of tree. I think I need to do a WHILE loop, but I have no idea how to do that. Please look at my codes.

```
breed [flies fly]
breed [suns sun]

turtles-own [energy]
flies-own [count-down]


to setup 

  clear-all 
  setup-suns
  setup-flies 
  setup-patches 

  reset-ticks 

end

to setup-suns
  ;; Create the sun

   set-default-shape suns "sun"

   create-suns 1 [
     setxy max-pxcor - 3
     max-pycor - 3
     set color yellow
     set size 7
   ]
end

to setup-flies

  set-default-shape flies "bee 2"
  create-flies number-fly [ set color white setxy random-xcor random-ycor set count-down 15]

end

to setup-patches

  ;; Create sky and grass

  ask patches
    [ set pcolor blue  ]
  ask patches with [pycor < min-pycor + 2]
    [ set pcolor 66 ]

  ;; Create trunk and branches

   ask patches with [ pxcor = -15 and pycor <= 0 ] [ set pcolor brown ]

   ask patches with [ pxcor = -15 and pycor < 8 and pycor > 0] [ set pcolor lime ]
   ask patches with [ pxcor = pycor - 15 and pycor <= 5 and pycor > 0 ] [ set pcolor lime ]
   ask patches with [ pxcor = (- pycor) - 15 and pycor <= 5 and pycor > 0 ] [ set pcolor lime ]
   ask patches with [ pxcor = pycor - 8 and pycor <= 2 and pxcor > -15 ] [ set pcolor lime ]
   ask patches with [ pxcor = (- pycor) - 22 and pycor <= 2 and pxcor < -15 ] [ set pcolor lime ]
   ask patches with [ pxcor = pycor - 1 and pycor <= -1 and pxcor > -15 ] [ set pcolor lime ]
   ask patches with [ pxcor = (- pycor) - 29 and pycor <= -1 and pxcor < -15 ] [ set pcolor lime ]

   ask patches with [ pxcor = 15 and pycor <= 0 ] [ set pcolor brown ]
   ask patches with [ pxcor = 15 and pycor < 8 and pycor > 0] [ set pcolor lime ]
   ask patches with [ pxcor = pycor + 15 and pycor <= 5 and pycor > 0 ] [ set pcolor lime ]
   ask patches with [ pxcor = (- pycor) + 15 and pycor <= 5 and pycor > 0 ] [ set pcolor lime ]
   ask patches with [ pxcor = pycor + 22 and pycor <= 2 and pxcor > 15 ] [ set pcolor lime ]
   ask patches with [ pxcor = (- pycor) + 8 and pycor <= 2 and pxcor < 15 ] [ set pcolor lime ]
   ask patches with [ pxcor = pycor + 29 and pycor <= -1 and pxcor > 15 ] [ set pcolor lime ]
   ask patches with [ pxcor = (- pycor) + 1 and pycor <= -1 and pxcor < 15 ] [ set pcolor lime ]   

   ask patches with [ pxcor = -26 and pycor = -3 ] [ set pcolor red ]  
   ask patches with [ pxcor = -10 and pycor = 5 ] [ set pcolor red ]            
   ask patches with [ pxcor = 21 and pycor = -1 ] [ set pcolor red ] 



end 

to go 

  move-flies 
  tick

end

to move-flies

  ask flies [ 

    set energy 6

    ifelse energy > 10 [

      ;rt random 50 lt random 50 jump random-float 1 ;

      let nearest-leaf min-one-of (patches with [pcolor = lime] ) [distance myself] ; Find the closest leaf within 5 grids - long range search.

      if is-patch? nearest-leaf [ ; If it is a leaf, and flies will be attracted to the leaf. 
       face nearest-leaf 
       ;set heading 45
       ;fd distance nearest-leaf
       rt random 50 lt random 50 jump random-float 5 ; Protential resources make flies move actively (fast movement).
       ;move-to nearest-leaf ;
     ]
    ]

    [
     ifelse pcolor != lime 
     [ rt random 50 lt random 50 jump random-float 1 ; Initialization - flies fly around to search their resources.
       continue]
     [ stay ] 

    ]
 ] 

end

to continue 

  let nearest-leaf min-one-of (patches in-radius 1 with [pcolor = lime] ) [distance myself] ; Find the closest leaf within 2 grids - short hops.

  ifelse is-patch? nearest-leaf [ ; If it is a leaf, and flies will be attracted to the leaf. 
     face nearest-leaf 
     fd random distance nearest-leaf
     ;ask patches in-radius 1 [set pcolor red]
     ;rt random 50 lt random 50 jump random-float 5 ; Protential resources make flies move actively (fast movement).
     ;move-to nearest-leaf ;
  ]
  [ 
    let turn-back min-one-of (patches with [pcolor = lime] ) [distance myself] ;
    ;set heading 180
    face turn-back
    jump random-float 5  ] 

    move-up ;Flies tend to move up through all branches by short hops. Need a while loop.

    ; Move down if they reach the top of tree
    let canopy patch-at-heading-and-distance 0 1
    let canopy-left patch-left-and-ahead 45 1
    let canopy-right patch-right-and-ahead 45 1

    if canopy != lime or canopy-left != lime or canopy-right != lime
       [
         move-down
       ] 

end

to move-up
  ask flies [
     set heading one-of [0 30 -30] 
  ]
end 

to move-down
  ask flies [
     set heading one-of [180 120 -120] 
  ]
end 

to stay

 set count-down count-down - 1 ;;decrement timer
 set label count-down
 if count-down = 0
  [
    rt random 50 lt random 50 jump random-float 1
    set label ""
    reset-count-down ;;it's another procedure   
  ]

end

to reset-count-down

  set count-down 30

end
```

I am sorry if you are confused by my codes. I appreciate your help. Thanks.

Kind Regards,

Ming

Comment: Can you give a specific example of a problem you're having?  Even better would be to condense the question and code to exemplify that problem in as little space as possible.

Answer (score 1):

From your description, I think you almost certainly don't want a `while` loop. In a NetLogo model's `go` procedure, you're only specifying what happens in a single tick. So you would only use `while` if need it to express something that happens all in a single instant, not a process that unfolds over multiple ticks.

(Agree with Frank this is too much code to post to have a good chance of getting help. It would take quite a while for me to read and study this much code, let alone try to help you with it. In this answer I've tried to extract and address a single aspect.)